# Kivymd NavigationDrawer Bug

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to use kivy NavigationDrawer to change screens after the user login using another screen.
The screens change alright, but the new screen is displayed on the first one.
The first screen does not disappear, so it looks like I have two screens merged into one.
This has bugged me for several days now and I cannot fix it.

Below are the codes

Python File

```
class UserProfile(MDScreen):
    pass
```

Kivy File

```
<UserProfile>:
    name: "user_profile" 

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Navigation Drawer"
        elevation: 4
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: "#e7e4c0"
        specific_text_color: "#4a4939"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:

        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager_second 
            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1 More Screen 1 More Screen 1 More"
                    halign: "center"
            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 2"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
            ScrollView: 
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        icon: "information-outline"
                        text: "Label1"
                        on_release: 
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager_second.current = "scr 1"
                    OneLineListItem:
                        icon: "information-outline"
                        text: "Label2"
                        on_release: 
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager_second.current = "scr 2"
                    OneLineListItem:
                        icon: "information-outline"
                        text: "Label3"

                    OneLineListItem:
                        icon: "information-outline"
                        text: "Label4"
```

I have tried everything I know and checked the documentation as well.